# Load xml configuration only once in .NET MVC Web API

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api2

I am working on an MVC Web API application. Now, for a new requirement, I want to be able to add some xml files in my solution, containing configuration. The XML will look like this:

```
<utils>
    <util>
        <enable>FALSE</enable>
        <name>JTDS.BackFlush</name>
        <operation>0040</operation>
        <attributes>
            <sender>SFCS</sender>
            <interface_id>JTDS</interface_id>
            <folder>C:\temp</folder>
        </attributes>
    </util>
    <util>
        <enable>TRUE</enable>
        <operation>0030</operation>
        <name>JTDS.Reprint</name>
        <attributes>
            <sender>SFCS</sender>
            <interface_id>JTDS</interface_id>
        </attributes>
    </util>
</utils>
```

Since this configuration is not - or rarely - changed. I want this configuration to be loaded only once, preferably into an object with the same properties. It would be good that when changes in this configuration are detected, the application is restarted automatically, as it's done with the web.config. Is there any way of doing this? Is the application_start the best place to do this?

Looking forward for answers!

Comment: Just de-serialize the file in your app start. I'd suggest that rather than having some special code to detect changes you just restart the site when you make these changes.

Comment: Yes, you can use Application Start method in the global.asax.cs file. Then you can deserialize data to object and cache it or you can have it in some static fields. I recommend to consider using json file for configuration your app. It is easy deserialize json file using Newtonsoft.Json.

Comment: The ideal way would be to use the cache and specify the file dependency so that the cache gets updated when the file has some change. This is easy with Microsoft Enterprise library